# if else check based on input in XQuery

Tags: xquery

I am trying to configure a if else check based on element response contain 'Y' but for some reason below logic is not working. Looking for your help here.

if value in $Response/Detail/Reefer is 'Y' then display only `<LiveReefer>` else display other tags.

```
<ns0:CargoTypeCd>
  let $_Reefer := data($Response/Detail/Reefer)
if ($_Reefer = 'Y') then
      <LiveReefer>{data($Response/Detail/Reefer)}</LiveReefer> 
    else 
        <Dry>{data($Response/Detail/Dry)}</Dry>
         <Dangerous>{data($Response/Detail/Dangerous)}</Dangerous>
          <OutOfGauge>{data($Response/Detail/OOG)}</OutOfGauge>
 </ns0:CargoTypeCd>
```

can you please validate If I am missing anything here.

Comment: Explain 'not working'.. What is the expected output and what did you get instead?

Comment: @har07  - I am getting result as expected. ideally if result match for Id condition then we shuld have only LIveReefer tag displayed not Dry, Dangerous and OutOfGauge. But here I am getting all 4.

Comment: You're really getting results from this code? It has numerous syntax errors, which I would expect to prevent it from working at all: no curly braces surrounding the FLWOR block, no `return` clause. If you're working with different code than what you've posted here, it's tough to help...

Answer (score 2):

The issue that you are having with the `if... then... else...` conditional expression is probably its scope. Because you didn't put parentheses around the three items in the  `then` clause, your XQuery processor will treat anything after the first item as outside the conditional expression. In order to fix it change your code to have parentheses, like such.

```
<ns0:CargoTypeCd xmlns:ns0="foo">
    {
        let $_Reefer := data($Response/Detail/Reefer)
        return
            if ($_Reefer = 'Y') then
                <LiveReefer>{data($Response/Detail/Reefer)}</LiveReefer>
            else 
                (
                    <Dry>{data($Response/Detail/Dry)}</Dry>,
                    <Dangerous>{data($Response/Detail/Dangerous)}</Dangerous>,
                    <OutOfGauge>{data($Response/Detail/OOG)}</OutOfGauge>
                )
    }
</ns0:CargoTypeCd>
```

This code also addresses several syntax errors in your original code: the lack of curly braces around the FLWOR code block and the lack of a `return` clause in your FLWOR expression.

Comment: Great! In that case, Kumarb, please mark this as the answer.